# How to cache videos in flutter

Tags: video, flutter, streaming

I am working on app in which we have a user feed. I am looking for any good library or approach to cache videos so that it will not be downloads every time.

Please recommend any good library of flutter.

Comment: why not download the video in the background, check it exist and use ?

Comment: You can use [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

Comment: @TinusJackson thankyou for your response, can you please provide any good example of downloading video in the background, I am completely new to flutter, So I am having a hard time to implement simple things.

Comment: @TinusJackson but that requires the video to be downloaded twice thus using twice the bandwidth doesn't it?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij No, it will still be on the device and then just check if it exist. See Marc's answer it is better than my comment

Comment: @TinusJackson This question is caching videos but not any general files. When it comes to videos the moment the user opens the app they expect view videos normally. We shouldn't show the user `You need to wait till it has completed downloading`. So first we need to play the video directly from the server. Then while it is playing it should be cached in the background. But the video_player plugin doesn't support caching thus it requires us to write something like Marc's answer thus downloading the video twice. On first play and second time caching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can download via HTTP like so:

```
static var httpClient = new HttpClient();
Future<File> _downloadFile(String url, String filename) async {
  var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  var response = await request.close();
  var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  return file;
}
```

This snippet requires https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider plugin.

You could also use different kinds of local storage. But this should get you started.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. It just downloads a file.

Comment: This is plain wrong. This snippet saves the content to the file handle AND gives the file back to the caller and BTW it seems that the author liked the answer by checking it and solved his problem

Comment: This is useful for downloading general files but not videos. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856969/how-to-cache-videos-in-flutter/58858903?noredirect=1#comment108385970_58856969

Comment: What’s the difference? A video is a file and an image is a file. No difference at all. It’s just a chunk of binary data. But anyway.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you download the whole video before being able to play it. Usually you only want to stream videos, which `VideoPlayer.network(...)`does.

Comment: please read the question. It was about "caching a video". Your argument might be right but it was not phrased exactly in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of discussion around this on flutter's page [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28094)

A package that works on similar principles  - https://pub.dev/packages/cached_video_player#-readme-tab-

Thanks!